# MySQL trim() not removing space inside a string

Tags: mysql

Given the value of `name` column: `AL TAIRAWI TRADING ESTABLISHMENT`

```
Update ae_companies set uniqueidentifier = CONCAT(trim(LEFT(name, 5)), '_', id, '_ae')
```

Above query produces this:

```
AL TA_6_ae
```

What I am looking for is this:

```
ALTA_6_ae
```

I have no idea why the `trim()` isn't working here.

Comment: `trim` is actually working; but it only removes leading and trailing spaces, not any spaces in the middle of the string. For that you need to use `replace`.

Comment: @mathielo. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replace()` instead of `trim()`.

```
Update ae_companies 
set uniqueidentifier = CONCAT(replace(LEFT(name, 5), ' ', ''), '_', id, '_ae')
```

[`TRIM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) isn't working *(doing the job you thought it does)* in your case because its description is:

> Remove **leading** and **trailing** spaces

When you do `LEFT(name, 5)` which produces `AL TA` all leading and trailing spaces are removed when you wrap this around `TRIM()` the way you did. In your case space character is neither at the last nor at the first position, so this is why your result doesn't change when trimmed.

What you're looking for is a `REPLACE($INPUT_STRING, ' ', '')` to truncate all occurences of space character within the input string.